# Novacode Docx MergeCells Paragraph Remove

Tags: merge, paragraph, removeall, novacode-docx

I'm using novacode docx for creating word document with c# but I have a problem with MergeCells. If I merge lots of cells, every cell put another paragraph in content. Can I remove paragraph in cells?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mins sharing your latest code?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for removing paragraph in cell.

```
t1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.Last().Remove(false);
```

For every paragraph you can use it.